# 404 component not found backend

Tags: custom-component

I developed a component extension, I Installed it on my Joomla in a regular server. I also received the success message after Installation.

It's table is added, all files under administrator and components (site part) are added. It is in menu part of back end too.

Yet when I click on menu item in Joomla back end to reach component page I receive:

**404 Component not Found.**

I used address bar with direct URL too, the same 404 Error.
Any points?

Comment: 1. does your component show up in the #__extensions table?  if not then it may not have installed properly and you may need to enter it manually. 2. is this the first time you have attempted to install it?  or is this an install of a component still in development?

Comment: Do you have the `componentname.php` file in `administrator/components/com_componentname/` ?